# Why does my generic Chinese intervalometer stop short of selected number of frames?

Tags: timelapse, intervalometer

I am using an intervalometer to make a time lapse video

I am using a Nikon D3300 with a 50mm f1.8 lens
Focus set to manual

*Camera Settings:*

**ISO**: 3200

**Shutter Speed** : 1/25 Seconds

**Apreture** : f1.8

*Intervalometer settings:*

**Interval** : 6 seconds

**Frames** : 150 frames

When I press start on the intervalometer device everything works with
the timing and shooting, but the problem is when it reaches 20 frames, it stops shooting automatically and resets the settings to default "00:00:00"

I formatted my 16gb SD CARD and I have a lot of space

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Best guess, the intervalometer is either bad or improperly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if the battery is marginal, that could brownout and consequently reset the unit after operating for a while.